# rails generate controller comments throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate comments controller using rails generate command but it is giving a weird error:-

```
$ rails generate controller comments
The name 'CommentsController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

I have checked but I don't have a comment controller. These are the commands I have tried:-

```
$ rails generate controller Comments create
The name 'CommentsController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.

$ rails generate controller comments
The name 'CommentsController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.

$ rails g controller Comments
The name 'CommentsController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again
```

Plz help me out here.

This is the GemFile:-

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'formtastic'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.11.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 3.5.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 1.2.0'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: FWIW, it works with new rails4. Could you try to `rails new test ; cd test ; rails g controller comments`?

Comment: It worked in the sample blog application given in rails guide. I am building an application based on blogging. I have other Users & Posts controller, but as soon as I tried to generate Comments controller it threw an error.. I am also using active admin. Could that be a possible problem?

Comment: May be some gem using it. Try as Smar said create new app with same gems used in app. If it won't work then it is used by some gem.

Comment: I tried creating a new app and the command worked. But I need this command to work in the current app. Can you guyz suggest some possible error points?

Comment: I think `active_admin` uses the comments.

Comment: edited my question... added gem file

Comment: See this: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/lib/active_admin . You can see `comments` directory in lib which is avoiding to create new `comments` directory.

Comment: Does that mean I have to rename comment model to something else? or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: There is a workaround for that but I am not getting now. It is better to use some other name.

Answer (score 3):

`active_admin` gem is using the same name `comments`. That is why rails generator not letting you to create `comments controller`. See this: github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/lib/active_admin. Here you can see `comments` directory. So it is better to use  some other name for your controller to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the comments in your admin section then you can turn it off.

Go to `/config/initializers/active_admin.rb` and write `config.allow_comments = false` . Once this is done you can generate your controller and there will be no conflict with active_admin.

You can read [active admin documentation](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#comments) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the `comments_controller` manually and it is working. `active_admin` might be an issue. I asked a friend but he did not face any such problems with `active_admin`. So, I am not sure what the problem was but right now, creating the controller manually works.

Comment: That means it is an issue with `rails generator`. I think there should be a namespace for gems and generator is not considering the `namespace`.